Tension in a ring rotating about its diameter
We have all seen the classic question to find the tension in a ring rotating about its own axis.
What about finding the variation of tension (with angle $\theta$) in a ring rotating about its diametrical axis?
My Question statement:
A metal ring of mass M and radius R is set rotating about an axis going through the diameter. Its angular velocity is $\omega$. Find tension as a function on angle $\theta$ from horizontal.
Figure:

What I have done
Doing a force balance along the vertical, and a centripetal force acting inwards, towards the central axis(as shown), and simplifying, we get:
$$T \sin \theta d\theta = dT \cos \theta$$
$$T \cos \theta d \theta + dT \sin \theta = {M R \omega^2 \over 2 \pi} \cos \theta d \theta$$
Let $T_0 = {M R \omega^2 \over 2 \pi}$,
Solving the two equations, we get:
$$\int_{T_0}^T dT = {T_0 \over 2} \int_0^{\theta} \sin 2 \theta d\theta$$
$$\therefore T = T_0 \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \sin^2 \theta \right)$$
Hence, we get that the tension at horizontal($\theta = 0$) is $T=T_0$, whereas tension at the top and bottom points(intersection of the ring and its axis) at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is $T=\frac{3}{2} T_0$.
This doesn't seem to make sense, since the top and bottom points are not moving, why would there be tension at those points?
Further, let's say the ring has Young's modulus $Y$, we can find its net elongation(by the definition of Young's modulus), but would it be possible to find out the equation of the curve it assumes while its rotating at the given angular velocity, $\omega$?
Note: This is a question that I have made up. It is a modification of the aforementioned classic problem.

Where does your second equation come from? I didn't understand that extra term of $Tcos\theta d\theta$.

I have a follow up question to this, and someone tell me if this should be a separate question.
Can I assume a half ring on either side of the axis. And that the tension being applied on the extremities of that half ring, be $T_e$. I visualize the motion of the center of mass of the half ring, that has a radius of $\frac{2R}{\pi}$, to be circular, with the same angular velocity as that of the axis. Would I be correct to assume that the forces that keep that center of mass in circular motion are the Tension force at the extremities?
Doing this gives me tension on the extremities to be $T_o$

@WebbWayne, The second equation comes from centripetal force acting on the $dm$ element in the figure. I have already simplified it(expanding $\sin(\theta + d \theta)$ ) and put it there.
As for the follow-up question.. It does make sense (to me), but the final goal of the question was to find the tension as a function of angle $\theta$. Either way, Pretty sure that the reason works out..


This doesn't seem to make sense, since the top and bottom points are not moving, why would there be tension at those points?

If you had a straight horizontal bar rotating about a vertical axis through its centre there would still be tension at the centre. Or if you had two small masses connected by a string and rotating about the middle of the string, there would still be tension at the middle of the string. Just because a point on an object is stationary does not mean that there cannot be tension at the point.
